# multiple assignment which property use in Bryntum scheduler

Tags: angular, bryntum-scheduler

multiple assignment which property use in Bryntum scheduler
I can show resources but assignment didn't plotting in scheduler.

Comment: Hi Pooja, your question is not very clear. What is the issue? What were you trying to do? What did you already try? Please edit your post to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use assignments (https://bryntum.com/docs/scheduler/api/Scheduler/view/Scheduler#config-assignments) that would contain array of event-to-resource relationships.

There is a demo that shows it: https://bryntum.com/examples/scheduler/multiassign/

You can also ask you questions in their forum (https://www.bryntum.com/forum/) - the answers are quick and to the point.